# Getting word of a char in string based on its location

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have a string, e.g.:

`"This is my very boring string"`

In addition, I have a location of a char in the string **without spaces**.

e.g.:

The location 13, which in this example matches the `o` in the word `boring`.

What I need is, based on the index I get (13) to return the word (boring).

This code will return the char (`o`):

```
re.findall('[a-z]',s)[13]
```

But for some reason I don't think of a good way to return the word boring.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is doable, but why aren't whitespace count as characters, where 13th would be e in very ?

Comment: what if 13th is punctuation, possibelre ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install and use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, which supports patterns with variable-length lookbehinds, so that you can use such a pattern to assert that there are exactly the desired number of word characters, optionally surrounded by white spaces, behind the matching word:

```
import regex
regex.search(r'\w*(?<=^\s*(\w\s*){13})\w+', 'This is my very boring string').group()
```

This returns:

```
boring
```

Comment: can yuo post a link to a site that demonstrates this ?

Comment: @Edward Yes, please run the demo here: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SecondhandMaroonIntegrationtesting

Comment: why variable length lookbehind, not really needed and it doe notter work ising \w without using `\W` the anti-word, will not worker at all

Comment: Nice one! You might include the demo link in your answer and make it non-read-only so that readers can see what happens when `13` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `\w+` to match words and keep accumulating the lengths of the matches until the total length exceeds to target position:

```
def get_word_at(string, position):
    length = 0
    for word in re.findall(r'\w+', string):
        length += len(word)
        if length > position:
            return word
```

so that `get_word_at('This is my very boring string', 13)` would return:

```
boring
```

Comment: It solves the problem. But there has to be a more elegant way of doing this, no?

Answer (score 1):

Do not require var length lookbehind which is slow and ugly.
Using a simple lookahead with a capture group will get the word.

This regex uses non-whitespace as the *character*.

`^(?:\s*(?=(?<!\S)(\S+))?\S){13}`

[demo 13th char](https://regex101.com/r/EO5nql/1)

Use word if need be but whatever the *character* sought it must
be used with the *anti-character* otherwise nothing will work,
it will stop because *ALL* characters mut be matched.

Examples:

- \w used with \W
- \s used with \S

[demo 1st char](https://regex101.com/r/ykddMr/1)

[demo 18th char](https://regex101.com/r/WLXXkj/1)

Comment: Speaking of "ugly", you need to re-write the text in your answer. English may not be your first language, but English 101 everywhere teaches that sentences begin with a capital letter and end with a terminator. "whick", "punct", "donter" and "possibelre" are not words. "punct" is lazy. Please show respect for the language.

Comment: Great solution, +1. Just note that the `13` in the question refers to the index 13, rather than the 13th non-space character, so in your case you would have to use `{14}` instead.

Comment: its a really almost an 'other wordly', kind of genius answer isnt it ? As I show you now :: When quant is 1, match and the last letter is `T`, the word returned in group 1 is `This`  https://regex101.com/r/ykddMr/1 .
When set to 18, match is `This is my very boring` the last letter is `g` the word returned in group 1 is `boring`

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution that strives for the elegance the OP desires:

```
def word_out_of_string(string, character_index):
    words = string.split()

    while words and character_index >= len(words[0]):
        character_index -= len(words.pop(0))

    return words.pop(0) if words else None

print(word_out_of_string("This is my very boring string", 13))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take in two arguments: a string and an index.

It will convert the index to be the same index equivalent to the original string.

Then, it will return the word that the character of the converted index belongs to in the original string.

```
def find(string,idx):
    # Find the index of the character relative original string
    i1 = idx
    for char in string:
        if char == ' ':
            i1 += 1
        if string[i1] == string.replace(' ','')[idx]:
            break

    # Find which word the index belongs to in the original string
    i2 = 0
    for word in string.split():
        for l in word:
            i2 += 1
            if i2 == i1:
                return(word)
        i2+=1

print(find("This is my very boring string", 13))
```

Output:

```
boring
```

Comment: This would not work if there are duplicating characters in the given string.

Answer (score 0):

If Python's alternative regex engine is used, one could replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings:

```
r'^(?:\s*\S){0,13}\s|(?<=(?:\s*\S){13,})\s.*'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q4O3sk/3/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\_(ツ)_/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python demo](https://repl.it/talk/share/Extract-boring/41238)

For the example string the `'o'` in `'boring'` is at index `13` after whitespace has been removed. If both `13`'s in the regex are changed to any number in the range `12-17`, `'boring'` is returned. If they are changed to `12`, `'very'` is returned; if they are changed to `18`, `'string' is returned.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^            : match beginning of string
(?:\s*\S)    : match 0+ ws chars, then 1 non-ws char, in a non-capture group
{0,13}       : execute the non-capture group 0-13 times 
\s           : match a ws char
|            : or
(?<=         : begin a positive lookbehind
  (?:\s*\S)  : match 0+ ws chars, then 1 non-ws char, in a non-capture group 
  {13,}      : execute the non-capture group at least 13 times
)            : end positive lookahead
\s           : match 1 ws char
.*           : match 0+ chars
```